# How to make sub delete queries faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, dataset, subquery, sql-delete

I want to ask question that is about making mysql subqueries more faster.This query is working good but it's almost running 2.50 hours when I enter that query:

```
delete from callspan where oid not in (select * from (select MIN(oid) from callspan b Group by b.endtime, b.starttime, b.person_oid,b.phonenumber_oid,b.contact,b.description,b.direction,b.duration) x);
```

How can I run this code more faster? Also, I tried to make it with JOIN but I don't do that.There is too much data in MIT's call dataset and I am training with that dataset.Do you have any solution for these type of queries?

Thanks, Kind Regards.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reassess your indexing strategy.

Comment: Prefix the query with explain, and post the result. Looks to me like callspan is extremely unnormalised though.

Comment: explain is not working for all of query but when I wrote it before the select queries its working.If you want I can send output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete c
  from callspan c
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( select MIN(oid) min_oid
         from callspan b 
        Group 
           by b.endtime
            , b.starttime
            , b.person_oid
            , b.phonenumber_oid
            , b.contact
            , b.description
            , b.direction
            , b.duration
      ) x
     ON x.min_oid = c.oid
  WHERE x.min_oid IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd028/1

Alternatively, you could reverse the logic - create a new table with only the rows that you want, then drop the old table and recreate it with the new data, then add indexes back onto that - it might be quicker...

```
CREATE TABLE new_callspan AS
SELECT x.*
  FROM callspan x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT person_oid
            , MIN(oid) min_oid
         FROM callspan
        GROUP
           BY person_oid
     ) y
    ON y.person_oid = x.person_oid
   AND y.min_oid = x.oid;

 DROP TABLE callspan;

 CREATE TABLE callspan AS SELECT * FROM new_callspan;

 DROP TABLE new_callspan;

 ALTER TABLE etc
```

Comment: This query's run time is similar with my own query.How can I work that faster?

Comment: It's 60 minutes left and query is not finished already.Are there any  solution to fix that slow issue?